# Keras record loss and accuracy of train and test for each batch

Tags: keras

I am using Keras to train a cnn and I need to record accuracy and loss for each batch. Is there any way to save the statistics? Following is the code I am using but the accuracy is `none`. Also it looks like the callback is suppressing progress bar.

```
class Histories(keras.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self, test_data):
    self.test_data = test_data

def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.train_acc = []
    self.test_acc = []
    self.train_loss = []
    self.test_loss = []

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    train_loss_batch = logs.get('loss')
    train_acc_batch = logs.get('accuracy')
    self.train_loss.append(train_loss_batch)
    self.train_acc.append(train_acc_batch)
    print('\nTrain loss: {}, acc: {}\n'.format(train_loss_batch, train_acc_batch))

    x, y = self.test_data
    test_loss_batch, test_acc_batch = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
    self.test_loss.append(test_loss_batch)
    self.test_acc.append(test_acc_batch)
    print('\nTesting loss: {}, acc: {}\n'.format(test_loss_batch, test_acc_batch))
```

To use the callback:

```
histories = my_callbacks.Histories((x_test, y_test))
model.fit(x_train_reduced, y_train_reduced, batch_size, epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[histories])
```

Comment: For Tensorflow 2.0 alpha, logs.get('acc') works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I need each time after calculating the gradient on the batch, counting the loss for the validation set and for the set set.

In the Keras API there are remarkable parameters:

```
steps_per_epoch, validation_steps
```

They set the number of examples for the era and validation, respectively. So, I wanted to set the size of the epoch in 20 examples, thereby artificially equating it to the size of `batch_size`. After that I create a `callback`, which is processed every time after the batch processing is completed:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
```

About this bug I wrote [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10387). So far I'm waiting for an answer. But I have a problem that still requires a solution.

Due to the fact that there is no simple answer to this question, it is necessary to crut. For this, you can refer to members of the class `Callback`. Here lies the validation set, on which you can test. This is done in this way:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(self.model.evaluate(self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]))
```

P.s. logs.get (`val_loss`) is considered after each era. In this regard, in it, at the first batch of the first era will lie `None`.

Comment: do ypou mean epoch by era?

Comment: I get this error AttributeError: 'LossHistory' object has no attribute 'validation_data'